# How can a border be placed beyond parent's boundary

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm stuck at a design challenge where I have to achieve following image described UI.

This is the closed accordion state:
[image]

And following is the open accordion state. You can see the red circled area where border height remains as initial state.
[image]

Following is a pseudo code for above UI arrangement which I have used.

```
<div class="card-wrapper" style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; border:1px solid #000; border-radius: 5px;">
    <div class="card-body" style="border-left: 10px solid #F00; border-top-left-radius: 10px; border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="card-accordion-body">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

My output is shown below:
[image]

Comment: multiple ways to do it: `shadow`, `pseudo-elements`, `position: absolute;` or `SVG`. But sicne you tagged it with bootstrap I will wait for someone more experienced with bootstrap to see if this can be solved purely with bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for giving so many suggestions @tacoshy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a pseudo-element positioned absolutely

```css
div {
  max-width: 450px;
  height: 75px;
  outline: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 2em auto;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 0 1em 1em;
  position: relative;
  transition: height .3s ease;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: .5em;
  background: red;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 1em 0 0 1em;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

div:hover {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit vitae, eligendi aperiam aut id illo neque nemo. Est, magnam assumenda.</p>
</div>
```